# WiFi roaming on Home network

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

Here is the setup.

Router is Cisco 837 with active gateway and DHCP configured. 2 linksys access points and one D-link connected to the switch ports and DHCP is disables on all of them. All the APs have same SSID and password encryption etc. Will I be able to roam on WiFi network.

Thanks

Imran

Answer (score 0):

If the SSID settings are the same you should be able to roam between your Linksys devices. However I wouldn't be surprised if roaming between the Linksys and D-Link boxes was problematic - manufacturers don't necessarily play nice when it comes to interoperability :)

Comment: I've a Cisco & a D-Link here. roaming is fine, other than devices tend to try hang onto one AP until the signal collapses, rather than optimally jumping to the strongest signal.

Comment: Tetsujin, client never roams when a stronger association is available. The NIC driver has a set threshold, and only when the signal quality of previous association drops below that threshold it will start searching for a better signal.

Your client NIC driver may contain a setting that you can change. Intel calls it "Roaming aggressiveness", and it's by default set to medium.

Comment: What you can do on the network side is disallow all data rates below 11Mb/s on the SSID. When client moves away from the antenna, the data rate drops with the distance. So once the data rate drops below 11Mb/s, AP will disassociate the client thus forcing it to roam.

Another thing you can do is lower the radio transmit power. That decreases the cell size, again forcing the client to roam faster